# Вытащить все ключи из словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть словарь, но в нем словарь в словаре. Как вытащить все ключи из "data" и сложить их в отдельный словарь

```
questionnaire = {
      "appType":"value",
      "step":"FULL",
      "data":{
        "amount":50000,
        "period":36,
        "loanPurpose":"ConstructionHouseroom",
      }
}
```

Comment: что вы хотите получить на выходе? Чем не устраивает `data = questionnaire["data"]` ?

Comment: `[ key if type(value)==str else [key, *list(value.keys())] for key, value in questionnaire.items() ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
questionnaire = {
      "appType":"value",
      "step":"FULL",
      "data":{
        "amount":50000,
        "period":36,
        "loanPurpose":"ConstructionHouseroom",
      }
}

print(list(questionnaire["data"].keys()))
```

Результат:

```
['amount', 'period', 'loanPurpose']
```